# How do I refresh data on my website on AWS S3?

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3

I am working on a pretty basic website where I am updating csv files which I display as tables using html/bootstrap. My problem is that even though I update the csv file the html pages are not updating. Also this is really inconsistent being that some html pages will update and others will not. I am trying to figure out when S3 decides to update changes or if I can do so manually. I should mention that I am routing the domain to S3 from namecheap.com.

Thank you in advance I am still very new to AWS.

Comment: I just want to confirm that did you disable cache when you refresh page?

Comment: Are you using AWS Cloudfront and S3 together or only S3?

Comment: @Victor I have never disabled cache in my browser

Comment: @Ashan yes that is correct I am only using S3 I am unfamiliar with Cloudfront

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 updates reflect immediately when you request downloads again.

**The issue is that you have not disabled your browser cache.** So your browser is using the cached html instead of downloading from S3.

To disable cache during development on Chrome for example, is to press F12 then go to Network tab and check Disable cache.

[image]

Do not close the window until you are happy with caches. If you do not want to keep the window open, alternatives are to use plugins or to modify your registry which are not really suggested.

Finally if you plan to use Cloudfront in the future, whenever you make an update to S3 and you will want to [invalid Cloudfront caches](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html) before they automatically expire.

Comment: Thank you very much I will give this a shot and follow up with the thread! Also I looked into CloudFront as @Ashan mentioned. I plan on updating my website every hour and I am wondering if S3 alone will cause me problems down the road?

Comment: If you start using cloudfront, you will need to invalidate caches, I added the link in my answer. If you are worrying that your clients will not be getting the latest version of your website, yes that will be a problem - but that is a problem no matter how you host your website. Browser caches is your best friend and worst enemy.

Comment: Got you, thank you! I do a lot more software/game dev than web dev so this was super helpful. Again I will follow up on my findings!

Comment: Thank you disabling caching works great for debugging, my changes are immediate. So Victor in your opinion do you think I will need cloudfront for a website I plan on updating every hour or are there methods I could use to improve S3 alone?

Comment: Happy to help, if this sovled your issue please mark it as the accepted answer. To answer your qusetion, if your website is public and have global customers, yes you need Cloudfront. Especially note that custom domain name HTTPS is not possible using S3 on its own. You can easily integrate cloudfront cache invalidation in your CI/CD pipeline or as a simpe script.